# Please install double-conversion library when building redex

Tags: makefile, autoreconf, redex

I am trying to build redex - unfortunately it fails with:

```
checking for ceil in -ldouble-conversion... no
configure: error: Please install double-conversion library
```

But I installed this library:

```
➜  double-conversion git:(master) ✗ sudo scons install          
[sudo] password for ligi: 
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `install' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

I installed it from https://github.com/google/double-conversion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution online.

What you have to do is open "configure.ac" in redex's main folder and replace `AC_CHECK_LIB([double-conversion],[ceil],[],[AC_MSG_ERROR(` with `AC_CHECK_LIB([double-conversion],[main],[],[AC_MSG_ERROR(`

Original solution here: http://qiita.com/takke/items/6f39aa4901cb7c7faac9

After that I was able to build

Comment: Thanks this worked - I do not speak the language that is on the solution you linked - thanks for making it accessible to me

Comment: Im hitting this same issue and the solution does not work for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Which system are you using? Ubuntu? And have you installed the double conversion library?

Comment: OSX. I was able to install on Ubuntu succesfully

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607316/cimpiling-facebook-redex-on-osx-yosemite?lq=1

Comment: I'm also on ubuntu, but I found this when looking for a solution. Maybe it can be of help... https://gist.github.com/duedal/7887803. In any case, googling for "folly" instead of "redex" can give you more results, since it's folly that needs double-conversion anyways

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed the double-conversion error in configure, so this shouldn't be a problem anymore.  Thanks for reporting it.