# Compiling Facebook Redex on OSX Yosemite

Tags: android, facebook, macos, redex

So I installed redex on Ubuntu last night and everything went smoothly.
I'm having trouble today setting it up on my Mac.

There are 3 errors I'm getting at this `autoreconf -ivf && ./configure && make && make install` step.

`Please install double-conversion library`

`Please install google-glog library`

`Please install google-gflags library`

I dont get these all at once. I got the first one so I followed the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599684/please-install-double-conversion-library-when-building-redex/36600655#36600655) but that didn't work so I just deleted that check from the configure.ac file. This led to the second error, which then led to the 3rd.

I'm not sure why this is happening, I followed the exact same steps as I did last night.

Any suggestions?

So I followed the suggestion from Ralph and now I've got a different error -

```
      ...
  "double_conversion::StringToDoubleConverter::StringToIeee(char const*, int, int*, bool) const", referenced from:
      folly::detail::str_to_float(folly::Range<char const*>*) in libfolly.a(Conv.o)
      folly::detail::str_to_double(folly::Range<char const*>*) in libfolly.a(Conv.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [redex-all] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there were bugs in the code that needed to get ironed out. The fun of early adopters ;)

https://github.com/facebook/redex/commits/master

It's working for me now.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do the following steps

`xcode-select --install` and `brew link --force openssl`

after that add `#include <stddef.h>` line into `third-party/folly/folly/portability/Malloc.h`

[see this post](https://github.com/facebook/redex/issues/15)

Comment: So now I'm getting this error - error: unknown type name 'size_t'
extern "C" size_t malloc_usable_size(void* ptr);
           ^
1 error generated.
make[4]: *** [portability/Malloc.lo] Error 1

Comment: have you added `#include <stddef.h>` ?

Comment: yah, turns out i needed to add it as the first include line

Comment: new error now,   "double_conversion::StringToDoubleConverter::StringToIeee(char const*, int, int*, bool) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<double>::value, double>::type folly::to<double>(folly::Range<char const*>*) in libfolly.a(json.o)
      std::__1::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<double>::value, double>::type folly::to<double>(folly::Range<char const*>*) in libfolly.a(dynamic.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Have you able solve this? I'm getting redex command not found error. Please provide help to make output apk